# Best practice: update/extend subclass class attribute

Tags: python, oop

This is just a little curiosity. I usually find myself updating a class attribute inherited in a subclass and I'd like to know how others deals with it. I know that I can't update them in the `__init__`: since it's a class attribute I would update it to the superclass instances as well. So I usually do something like this:

```
class A(object):
    attribute = {
        1: 'a',
        ...,
        5: 'e',
    }

class B(A):
    attribute = {
        1: 'a',
        ...,
        5: 'e',
        6: 'f',
    }
```

But, since I like to follow the DRY principle as much as possible and I'd like to know if someone use a more elegant way to do this without completely copy and paste the attribute.

As asked this is a concrete example with Django forms:

```
class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):

    username = forms.EmailField(label=_('Email'))

    error_messages = {
        'inactive': _('This account is inactive.'),
        'invalid_login': _('Please enter a correct username and password. '
                           'Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.'),
        'unconfirmed': _('Your account is not confirmed yet. Please '
                         'check your email and follow the instructions '
                         'in order to activate it.'),
    }

    def confirm_login_allowed(self, user):
        super(LoginForm, self).confirm_login_allowed(user)
        if not user.confirmed:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['unconfirmed'],
                code='unconfirmed')
```

The **error_messages** attribute is inherited from django.contrib.auth.forms.AuthenticationForm but I wanted to add the 'unconfirmed' key so I had to copy and paste the 'inactive' and 'invalid_login' keys too.

Comment: It's hard to give you recommendations without a more concrete example. Can you share any? You should also clarify some terminology: what do you mean by "...inherited from a subclass..."? Did you mean superclass or parent class?

Comment: ops sorry I forgot to write that class B inherits from A, but if you want I can write a concrete example

Comment: I think it would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do put it in `__init__` then every instance of the subclass (`B` in this case), will see the update.  The only time you would not is if you specify the class directly:

```
B.attribute[6]
# KeyError
```

One way without using `__init__` is to:

```
class B(A):
    attribute = A.attribute.copy()
    attribute.update({
          6: 'f',
          7: 'g',
          })

print(B().attribute) # --> {1:'a', ..., 5:'e', 6:'f', 7:'g'}
print(A().attribute) # --> {1:'a', ..., 5:'e'}
```

The point to remember is that a class's code is executed as it is created, so you can use normal Python to make adjustments.

Comment: Yeah I was looking for something like this, but with this exact approach I would update A.attribute too.

Comment: @Dorian: Ack, forgot the `.copy()` -- that won't update `A`.

Comment: Yup I was just writing the same!

Comment: Dictionaries also have an `update` method that I rather like for things like this: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_update.htm

Comment: @NightShadeQueen: an `.update()` would change `A`'s `attribute` as well, which the OP did not want.

Comment: copy, then update. Really all it does is let me avoid typing a dictionaries's name over and over again if I have multiple things I want to add to a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
class A(object):
    attribute = {
        1: 'a',
        5: 'e',
    }

class B(A):
    attribute = A.attribute.copy()
    attribute[6] = 'f'

print(A.attribute)  # -> {1: 'a', 5: 'e'}
print(B.attribute)  # -> {1: 'a', 5: 'e', 6: 'f'}
```

Comment: This solution is the same as the accepted answer -- what was the point?

Comment: @Ethan: Probably because it was written before you edited yours and made them the same.

Comment: Never fails -- I left mine alone for over an hour, got tired of waiting, so improved the `print()` statements along with an improvement suggested by NightShadeQueen, and then you look.  :/  At any rate, your class B is exactly as mine was, so I still don't get the point of your answer (It looked to me like you added your answer nearly an hour after mine was accepted, but maybe that was just an artefact of SO's time keeping?)